# Python Excel String Column Difference

Tags: python

```
| Text1                          | Text2                   | Change         |
|:-------------------------------|:------:-----------------| -----:---------|
| This is Mango. This is Banana  | This is Banana          | This is Mango. |
| This is Mango.                 | This is Mango, Banana   | , Banana       |
```

Want to derive Change column from Text1 and Text2 as above. Above one is excel data / DATAFRAME

Below code is working fine on Text but not DATAFRAME

```
import difflib
```

define original text
taken from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services

```
original = ["About the IIS", "", "IIS 8.5 has several improvements related", "to performance in large-scale scenarios, such", "as those used by commercial hosting providers and Microsoft's", "own cloud offerings."]
```

define modified text

```
edited = ["About the IIS", "", "It has several improvements related", "to performance in large-scale scenarios."]
```

initiate the Differ object

```
d = difflib.Differ()
```

calculate the difference between the two texts

```
diff = d.compare(original, edited)
```

output the result

```
print ('\n'.join(diff))
```

=> Output as below

```
 python comparing-strings-difflib.py
  About the IIS
  
- IIS 8.5 has several improvements related
?  ^^^^^^

+ It has several improvements related
?  ^

- to performance in large-scale scenarios, such
?                                        ^^^^^^

+ to performance in large-scale scenarios.
?
```

Comment: `diff` was created to compare strings (especially to compare source code) and it will not work with `DataFrame`.

Comment: maybe you should use `df['Change'] = df.apply(function_name)`  to run own function on every row separatelly and compare values from two columns.

Answer (score 1):

`diff` was created to compare strings (especailly `source code`)

You should use

```
df['Change'] = df.apply(function_name, axis=1)
```

to run own function on every row and compare both text in row.

But using `Diff()` is not useful to get changes because it gives result as text.
You should use `SequenceMatcher` to get it as tuples

```
(operation, text1_start, text1_end, text2_start, text2_end)
```

---

To create `DataFrame` I had to add missing rows in column `Text2` and I use `None` to recognize missing rows.

```
diff_row_number = len(original) - len(edited)

if diff_row_number > 0:
    edited = edited + [None]*diff_row_number
elif diff_row_number < 0:    
    original = original + [None]*(-diff_row_number)
```

If you use empty string `""` then you will no need part `if text2 is None:`

---

Minimal working code

```
import pandas as pd
import difflib

original = ["About the IIS", "", "IIS 8.5 has several improvements related", "to performance in large-scale scenarios, such", "as those used by commercial hosting providers and Microsoft's", "own cloud offerings."]
edited = ["About the IIS", "", "It has several improvements related", "to performance in large-scale scenarios."]

#d = difflib.Differ()
#diff = d.compare(original, edited)

#for line in diff:
#    print(line)

# fill missing lines    
diff_row_number = len(original) - len(edited)

if diff_row_number > 0:
    edited = edited + [None]*diff_row_number
elif diff_row_number < 0:    
    original = original + [None]*(-diff_row_number)

df = pd.DataFrame({
   'Text1': original,
   'Text2': edited,
})

def compare_row(row):
    text1, text2 = row
    
    if text2 is None:
        return 'remove: ' + text1
    else:
        sm = difflib.SequenceMatcher(a=text1, b=text2)
        opcodes = sm.get_opcodes()
        
        changes = []
        
        for item in opcodes:
            if item[0] != 'equal':
                name, a1,a2, b1,b2 = item
                changes.append( name + ' : ' + text1[a1:a2] + ' : ' + text2[b1:b2] )
                
        return '\n'.join(changes)

# --- main ---

df['Change'] = df.apply(compare_row, axis=1)

print(df['Change'])
```

Result:

```
0                                                     
1                                                     
2                                 replace : IS 8.5 : t
3                                 replace : , such : .
4    remove: as those used by commercial hosting pr...
5                         remove: own cloud offerings.
Name: Change, dtype: object
```

---

**EDIT:**

The same with empty strings instead `None`

```
import pandas as pd
import difflib

original = ["About the IIS", "", "IIS 8.5 has several improvements related", "to performance in large-scale scenarios, such", "as those used by commercial hosting providers and Microsoft's", "own cloud offerings."]
edited = ["About the IIS", "", "It has several improvements related", "to performance in large-scale scenarios."]

#d = difflib.Differ()
#diff = d.compare(original, edited)

#for line in diff:
#    print(line)

# fill missing lines    
diff_row_number = len(original) - len(edited)

if diff_row_number > 0:
    edited = edited + [""]*diff_row_number
elif diff_row_number < 0:    
    original = original + [""]*(-diff_row_number)    

df = pd.DataFrame({
   'Text1': original,
   'Text2': edited,
})

def compare_row(row):
    text1, text2 = row
    
    sm = difflib.SequenceMatcher(a=text1, b=text2)
    opcodes = sm.get_opcodes()
    
    changes = []
    
    for item in opcodes:
        if item[0] != 'equal':
            name, a1,a2, b1,b2 = item
            changes.append( name + ' : ' + text1[a1:a2] + ' : ' + text2[b1:b2] )
            
    return '\n'.join(changes)

# --- main ---

df['Change'] = df.apply(compare_row, axis=1)

print(df['Change'])
```

Result: (`delete` instead of `remove`)

```
0                                                     
1                                                     
2                                 replace : IS 8.5 : t
3                                 replace : , such : .
4    delete : as those used by commercial hosting p...
5                     delete : own cloud offerings. : 
Name: Change, dtype: object
```

Comment: you can mark answer as accepted and few minutes later you can upvote it.